# HTML5 History redirect like 301

Tags: html, redirect, html5-history

Lets say my site has some 301 redirects.

If I had no ajax navigation, and I click link `http://example.com/page1` (from main page) - it would answer 301 redirect to `http://example.com/page2`. So now if I press "back" button in browser I would go to main page (not `/page1`).

Is there a way to implement this with html5 history navigation? It looks like I should wait for server response, and if it says there's gonna be redirect - I do not do history.pushState and load next page. And if next one has no redirect - I'm doing `history.pushState`. Or am I misunderstanding something?

Is there any kind of routing library that supports such `301` redirects?

Comment: I know that such a questions are always a little "nervous", but could You please provide some informations on: why? What is your objective? Why PHP is not enough? Maybe there is some other way of solving this? And what dou you mean by html5? Javascript can be used?

Comment: I have to fix such wrong "back" behaviour on one of sites. There's some ajax navigation through houses on the map (choose house, choose section, choose floor, choose flat), so when I click on the house - I should go to page where I'm choosing section. Sometimes there is only one section, so I don't really need to "choose" it, js just redirects to section's page. Now I can't go back to house selection from the floor view, since it forwards me to section and it forwards to floor again. I wonder if I could fix that without touching backend.

Comment: Maybe you should try to change the default click action? I mean, If there are many section, click href = sections decide, if there is one section, click href = next step. So in that case during the map creation, you also create a "possible map of clicks" for each house. Thix can be dificult. Another option is to display information with section decision even if there is only one section. It is marked as default, and the user must click next. I it rasonable, so the user knows there is only one section, and the algorithm is same for each house. I should use this option. It build good habits! :)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for that. In fact, the History API is just a way to pass the URL you say it is to the browser.

If the user navigates back and forth, 301 redirects will just be followed like they always do.

Comment: That is what I mean in my first comment to question. +1 from me.